# The linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{8}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ What is the dimension of kernel of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{8}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that exist $v_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $T(v_0)\neq 0$.
What is the  dimension of kernel of $T$?

How can I start to answer this question? I know the kernel is the set of all zeros of the linear transformation. However, how does the information that there exists $v_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that $T(v_0)\neq 0$, help me solve this?

*P.S. I'm a beginner in algebra and in English, so if you can use more words than symbols, that would help me a lot.*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Should your $\mathbb{R}^n$s be $\mathbb{R}^8$s, or vice versa? Either way doesn't change the question much.

Comment: Thanks! Nop, the statement is written the same.

Comment: I'm a little confused then, because we would require $v_0 \in \mathbb{R}^8$, i.e. $n=8$, to even be able to apply $T$ to it, since $T$ is only defined on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^8$. I suspect there may be a misprint in your question and $8$ is meant to be $n$, since $8$ is quite an arbitrary number to ask this for, and a lot of questions like this will be asked with an $n$. Or, is there some detail in the question missing in the post. Anyways, I've posted an answer which gives as much detail as possible with what you've provided.

Comment: I'm a little confused too, but as I said I'm a beginner in the study of linear algebra and therefore I thought I was probably missing something, and that was the reason I brought the issue here on the website. I looked for some similar questions on the internet and they all seemed to have more information, but I'm still grateful for your help. When I have the opportunity, I will question my teacher about this statement.

Comment: Yes, $n$ snd $8$ need to be the same throughout.

Comment: I went to find out and yes, the question was missing something, the correct question should be what is the dimension of the kernel!
I'm sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel is some hyperplane ($7$-dimensional subspace) not containing $v_0$. That’s the best we can say. (Apply the nullity-rank theorem. We know $T$ cannot be the zero map, and hence has $1$-dimensional image.)